# Numbers of Lubavitcher Rebbe maamorim

Tags: chabad

I want to know how many maamorim the Rebbe said, and how many are *muga* and *bilti muga*?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://crownheights.info/assets/2019/04/%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A7-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9F.pdf) catalog, there were 1,562 maamorim in total. Of these, 192 were edited and 21 were partially edited.

Comment: what does it mean for the 21 partially edited 
where can we find them?

Comment: Everything is available in Torat Menachem Hitvaadiyut, both reviewed, partially reviewed and unreviewed. The catalog apparently doesn't include anything that was previously printed from Torat Menachem for the balance of 5751 or any of 5752. In my personal library, I have everything from 5710 thru 5752 and some material that the Rebbe said or wrote prior to 5710 even as early as 5704. There were things published in Israel (Kfar Chabad) that are not listed with Kehot.

Comment: @L770 They're printed in the new (seasonal) melukat under הוספות. Each one will have the background and details in the footnotes.